# Is this an expected behavior of an ARIMA(0,0,4,1,1,1)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality, differencing

I have data of daily sales and want to make a forecast in SPSS modeler, however I'm getting a result that I can't explain. The plot is inserted below. The fit is the red line and the blue is the historical actual sales. So the forecast starts where the red line ends.

Looking at information regarding the fitted model, we observe that the model is an $\text{ARIMA}(0,0,4)$ which is equivalent to $\text{MA}(4)$, thus our model in a mathematical form is given by the stochastic process

\begin{equation}
 X_t = \mathbb{E}[X_t] + \epsilon_t+\sum_{i=1}^{4}\theta_i\epsilon_{t-i} = \mathbb{E}[X_t]+\epsilon_t + \theta_{1}\epsilon_{t-1}+\theta_{2}\epsilon_{t-2}+\theta_{3}\epsilon_{t-3}+\theta_{4}\epsilon_{t-4}
\end{equation}

where $\epsilon_t,...,\epsilon_{t-4}$ are white noise error terms and $\theta_1,...,\theta_4$ are the parameters to be tuned.

**Question:** Is there an explanation for the horrible forecast using the equation above or does it possibly depend on something else?

**NOTE:** I do understand that fitting an ARMA model to seasonal data might not be ideal and that this types of models are not optimal for long term forecasting (I do use neural prophet instead that works very good) but I'm trying to understand how SPSS modeller works and if I've made a mistake in setting the parameters in SPSS or if the below is actually a reasonable result to expect given the mathematics.

[image]
[image]

**EIDT:** Following the answer of Richard Hardy, I removed the seasonal differencing. Now the result is simply constant with not only constant mean but also with zero variance:

[image]

Comment: Hi Richard, my sincere apologies I really thought I had already accepted it, but I apparently only upvoted it. Your answer was perfect and thank you very much!

Comment: No problem at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is as expected. This is a result of seasonal differencing. The effects of the MA, SAR and SMA components die out over time, and the forecast converges to one where each season has its own constant forecast. Asymptotically (in terms of a growing forecast horizon), it is as if your time series consists of $m$ independent random walks where $m$ is the number of seasons. The optimal forecast for each of them is the last observed value. These constants alternate as the seasons do.

I would consider a model without seasonal differencing instead. If you want to maintain some seasonal variation in the forecast, consider regression with ARMA errors where the regressors are seasonal dummies or Fourier terms. That would give you something similar to your original forecast but smoother (in case of Fourier terms) and on a different level. Perhaps relevant: Rob J. Hyndman ["Forecasting with long seasonal periods"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality) (2010).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I removed the differencing and the result is now an ARIMA(0,1,8). The forecast is just constant. Please check my edit.

Comment: @Parseval, yes, that is what you expect from ARIMA(0,1,8). The forecast becomes constant after the first 8 periods. If you want to maintain some seasonal variation in the forecast, consider regression with ARMA errors where the regressors are seasonal dummies or Fourier terms. That would give you something similar to your original forecast but smoother (in case of Fourier terms) and on a different level. How many seasons are there? Perhaps relevant: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/

Comment: Why do the forecasts become constant after 8 periods? I can't understand why by looking at the ARIMA equation. I'm simply adding 8 terms that are multiplied with noise. That Fourier solution was neat! I assume that's not possible to implement in SPSS modeler then but needs to be done manually in R/Python. Thanks!

Comment: @Parseval, check out some textbook material on forecasts from MA(q) models. You will see that the first q forecasts (1 step ahead, 2 steps ahead, ..., q steps ahead) vary but after that the forecasts stay constant. I have no experience with SPSS for time series forecasting, but I do no think SPSS offers much in that regard. It is mostly suited for other types of data and analyses.